# How to correct: The content model of a complex type must consist of 'annotation' in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am working with a 3rd party xml and I was trying to generate a class from it.
However I am seeing the warning:

```
The content model of a complex type must consist of 'annotation' (if present); followed by zero or one of the following: 'simpleContent', 'complexContent', 'group', 'choice', 'sequence', or 'all'; followed by zero or more 'attribute' or 'attributeGroup'; followed by zero or one 'anyAttribute'.
```

This is a snippet of the schema section in question.

```
<xs:element name="import">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="action" type="actionEnum" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>         
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">           
            <xs:element ref="Field1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Field2" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Field3" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Field4" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Field5" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Field6" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am not real familiar with writing xml schemas.  I tried researching this error but came up empty. I'm not sure how to correct this.  Any advice?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide an example of the XML for which you're trying to write an XSD.

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with.  The schema they sent me has 47K lines.

Comment: Does the error message come with a line number, by any chance? So that you could shows us this part?

Comment: What I enclosed was were the error was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown us is nonsense: if an element has simple content then it doesn't have child elements, so specifying an xs:choice with xs:element children inside xs:simpleContent makes no sense at all. But there's no way to correct it without knowing what you're actually trying to achieve.